# How to set Spline animation as a Wordpress background?

Tags: wordpress, animation, frontend, spline, ui-design

First post!  I know it's frowned on but I used a Themify pagebuilder to make a 2 page website.

I'm looking to set this Spline animation as a Wordpress background. The client wants it to move as the user scrolls down the page - slightly out of my depth here so any help is greatly appreciated!! Hit me up if you need to see the website too (it's still under development)

Here is the demo Spline animation: https://my.spline.design/untitled-722bf8562e756385ed6d85882591b059/

Thanks in advance!

~ weezy

Comment: Convert spline to canvas image

Comment: https://elementslib.com/ue_widgets/spline-3d-responsive-background-widget-for-elementor

Comment: Could you solve it? I have the same doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and my solution was to set "Auto zoom" in "Yes" in the "Play Settings" configuration of Spline.

[Spline_config_playsettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x9y4.png)